# Web Scraping with Multiprocessing in Python Stalls Randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am attempting to scrape a list of urls using a function called `data_finder`, where a url is the only argument. The list of urls is called `urls`.

To speed up the process, I am using the multiprocessing package in Python 3 on Windows 10. The code I am using is below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(10)
    records = p.map(data_finder, urls)
    p.close()
    p.join()
    print('Successfully exported.')
    with open('test.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(records, outfile)
```

The problem I am having is that sometimes the code freezes and is unable to continue, but other times it does work as expected. Whenever it does freeze though, it is usually in the last 10 urls. Is this a common occurrence or is there a solution to this?

Comment: Have you tried timing the request call to check if that is what is stalling?
From my understanding of 'sometimes' it looks to me like the network is causing the delay. Can you check?

Comment: Looks like you're right - the request is being timed out. Just seems strange that it gets so far through the list of URLs before timing out.

Comment: Have posted my comment as an answer so you can approve and mark the question as solved. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried timing the request call to check if that is what is stalling? From my understanding of 'sometimes' it looks to me like the network is causing the delay.